# Adding class to element after scroll

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on showing/hiding a nav element based on scrolling behavior. Once the user scrolls and scrolls past the nav element, I add a class to make it sticky but keep it out of view. Then once the user stops scrolling I add another class to the transition the element into view. Once the user scrolls again that class needs to be removed again and the nav disappears again.

This is the JS

```
let mobile_toolbar = document.querySelector(".mobile-toolbar");

    let mobile_toolbar_top = (mobile_toolbar.offsetTop) + 50;

    let scrollpos = window.scrollY;

    let timer = null;

    window.addEventListener(
      "scroll",
      function () {
        scrollpos = window.scrollY;
        console.log(timer)
        if (timer !== null) {
          if (scrollpos > mobile_toolbar_top) {
            mobile_toolbar.classList.add("mobile-toolbar__hidden");
            mobile_toolbar.classList.remove("mobile-toolbar--fixed");
            clearTimeout(timer);
          } else {
            mobile_toolbar.classList.remove("mobile-toolbar__hidden");
            mobile_toolbar.classList.remove("mobile-toolbar--fixed");
            clearTimeout(timer);
          }
        }
        if (scrollpos > mobile_toolbar_top) {
          timer = setTimeout(function () {
            mobile_toolbar.classList.add("mobile-toolbar--fixed");        
          }, 400);
        }
      },
      false
    );
```

As you can see I'm setting a timer to detect when the user stops scrolling and also check the scroll position to determine whether the add the fixed class or not. However, this isn't quite working as I'd like as the nav once slides down as soon as I scroll past itself and then disappears again as the timer is already not null at this point. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my cod or if there's a better way to detect when the user has stopped scrolling? Vanilla JS only please as I'm trying not to use jQuery

Comment: [Intersection_Observer_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) make your work easy

Answer (score 0):

you can refer a below code (it's tell you when user stop scrolling)

```
<html>
 <body onscroll="bodyScroll();">


 <script language="javascript">
    var scrollTimer = -1;
    function bodyScroll() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      if (scrollTimer != -1)
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
      scrollTimer = window.setTimeout("scrollFinished()", 500);
    }
    function scrollFinished() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  </script>

  <div style="height:2000px;">
    Scroll the page down. The page will turn red when the scrolling has finished.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't set the on scroll on the body like that so I've tried this but get scrollFinished is not defined:  function bodyScroll() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";

      if (scrollTimer != -1)
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);

      scrollTimer = window.setTimeout("scrollFinished()", 500);
    }

    function scrollFinished() {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  
    window.addEventListener("scroll",function () {
      bodyScroll()
    }
  );

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:
https://codepen.io/len0xx/pen/JjadOgR

```
const toolbar = document.querySelector('.mobile-toolbar')
const mobileToolbarTop = (toolbar.offsetTop) + 50
let previousScroll = 0
let previousTimeout = 0

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const currentScroll = window.scrollY

    if (currentScroll > mobileToolbarTop) {
        if (currentScroll > previousScroll) {
            toolbar.classList.add('mobile-toolbar__hidden')
            toolbar.classList.remove('mobile-toolbar--fixed')
        }
        else {
            toolbar.classList.remove('mobile-toolbar__hidden')
            toolbar.classList.add('mobile-toolbar--fixed')
        }
    }
    
    if (previousTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(previousTimeout)
    }
    
    previousTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        const newScroll = window.scrollY
        if (newScroll <= currentScroll) {
            toolbar.classList.remove('mobile-toolbar__hidden')
            toolbar.classList.add('mobile-toolbar--fixed')
        }
    }, 300)
    previousScroll = currentScroll
})
```